# Как избавиться от такого эффекта после нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: android, android-button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На кнопку в качестве `background` повешен такой селектор:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/color_btn_pressed_true" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/color_btn_pressed_false" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Но после нажатия какое-то мгновение остаётся тень именно справа и слева. Как от неё избавиться? Думаю, дело в стилях, но пробовал использовать свой стиль, где писал `background`, — не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"